# Serve static pdf files in solution folder - in MVC pipeline , with different route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

One of my old project we do have a static content file folder named XYZ which we are keeping in the same location fo the root.

Currently we are directly passing the url like 'siteaddress/XYZ/test.pdf' or siteaddress/XYZ/2020/Test1.pdf to get the pdf files.

Now we have a requirement to store some of the confidential files also in the path. So we are planning to restrict the direct access to the path and serve via MVC pipeline

we have added a handlers to enable the requests from the folder, to go through mvc pipeline

```
<add
      name="ManagedPdfExtension"
      path="XYZ/*/*.pdf"
      verb="GET"
      type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
/>
      <add
      name="ManagedPdfInnerFolderExtension"
      path="CommonFiles/*/*.pdf"
      verb="GET"
      type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
/>
```

Also created a method to return the file in controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("XYZ/{attachmentName}")]
public ActionResult CommonFiles(string attachmentName)
{
    var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/XYZ/"+ attachmentName);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string fileName = "Test.pdf";

    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = true,
        FileName = fileName
    };

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader(CoreConstants.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader(CoreConstants.WindowTarget, CoreConstants.WindowTargetBlank);
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

This code works ok with files which are directly under folder XYZ

That means if I try a url like

siteaddress/XYZ/test.pdf which is working.

But for the pdf that are inside another folder, I am not able to get with the existing approach.
Since we have only single param `attachmentName` defined in the method i couldn't get the files under subfolders.

Is there any way to do the same in MVC ??

Because of some reasons, I cannot move all these items to database , change the folder structure . Also i cannot create a mapping table like

url : key and use the key instead.

Th urls are coming from a common table which is used in many applications. So changing that is bit difficult.

If the folder and subfolders are limited then may be with multiple route i could handle this. But here the subfolder number can be a variable too.

In fact from the following urls

```
 siteadress/XYZ/abc/bn/test.pdf 
  siteadress/XYZ/abc/cf/bn/test.pdf 
  siteadress/XYZ/abc/bn/test.pdf
```

is there any way to make it hit a single controller method with a string params like

```
 abc/bn/test.pdf
abc/cf/bn/test.pdf 
abc/bn/test.pdf
```

??

Answer (score 0):

Added a route with * in the property part.

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("CommonFiles/{*any}")]
        public ActionResult CommonFiles(string attachmentName)
        {
            var filePathWithName = this.RouteData.Values["any"];
            var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/CommonFiles/"+ filePathWithName);
            path = path.Replace("//", "/").Replace("/","//");
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            string fileName = "Test.pdf";

            var cd = new ContentDisposition
            {
                Inline = true,
                FileName = fileName
            };

            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader(CoreConstants.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader(CoreConstants.WindowTarget, CoreConstants.WindowTargetBlank);
            Response.BufferOutput = false;
            return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
        }
```